# Аналог min-content CSS3 или родительский блок по ширине дочернего

Tags: html, css, css3

Как можно сделать ширину родительского блока по ширине дочернего, кроме как установить свойство ширины родителю `width: min-conten;`, так как поддержка этого свойства оставляет желать лучшего.

```js
function wrap200px(){
  document.getElementById("wrap").style.width = "200px";
}
function wrapAuto(){
  document.getElementById("wrap").style.width = "auto";
}
function mcOn(){
  document.getElementById("parent").classList.add("parent_min-content");
}
function mcOff(){
  document.getElementById("parent").classList.remove("parent_min-content");
}
```

```css
.parent{
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.parent_min-content{
  width: -moz-min-content;
  width: -webkit-min-content;
  width: min-content;
}
.children{
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color:white;
}
.buttons{
  margin-top:30px;
}
.wrap{
  width:auto;
  padding:10px;
  background-color: black;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrap" id="wrap">
 <div class="parent" id="parent">
    <span class="children">Раздватричетыре пятьшестьсемьвосемь</span>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
 <button onclick="wrap200px()">[1]<br>black->(width: 200px)</button>
 <button onclick="wrapAuto()">[4]<br>black->(width: auto)</button><br>
 <button onclick="mcOn()">[2]<br>red->(width: min-content)</button>
 <button onclick="mcOff()">[3]<br>red->(width: inherit)</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Что насчет `display: inline-block`?

Comment: а он уже там прописан

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать такой вариант с `flex`:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: red;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

.children {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: white;
}

.wrap {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap" id="wrap">
  <div class="parent" id="parent">
    <span class="children">Раздватричетыре пятьшестьсемьвосемь</span>
  </div>
</div>
```